# Prolog- Pattern matching strings connected by operators

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, operators, matching

Still kind of new to prolog and have run into an issue. I understand in prolog you can reprsent data like so : name+date+time . If I had a list of data structred like this how could I use pattern matching with in that list? For example if I wanted a predicate to evaulate to true if it takes two "name+date+time" values and
is only true if the name of the first does not equal the name of the second. Ive tried:

```
 notEqual([A+B+C, D+E+F]) :-
      A \= D.
```

But this doesnt pattern match as I expected. How would I work with values in this form?

Comment: Show us the usage that fails

Comment: sorry i thought it was clear, I try not to post too much details because then people get mad at you for "trying to get them to do your project for you".  for example if i passed this list into notEqual: [noah+jul+2, john+jun+6], it should return true (but it does not) since noah \= john. How would I properly compare noah and john?

Comment: Your code works... Maybe you want to do: `notEqual([A+B+C, D+E+F]) :- A \= D.`(you can replace `B`, `C`, `E`, `F` with `_` to avoid singleton variable errors). Query: `?- notEqual([noah+jul+2, john+jun+6]). true`. And a suggestion: don't mind if somenoe tell you "trying to get them to do your project for you", we arre here to help you and, the more you are clear, the more we can help you.

Comment: totally meant D isntead of B, brain fart of my end(edited to reflect this). Switching the extra variables to _ did work though! thanks for the advice! Must have been causing an error somehow (or maybe when i deleted and retyped i added something i thought i missed!)

Comment: @NoahCabral people don't think that, if you post detail, you're wanting them to do work for you. On the contrary, it's usually when less is posted. You do need to show what you tried and what exactly fails. It's hard to tell from your question how you intend to call your predicate.